# Which is the third most visited Greek island after Santorini & Mykonos?

Tags: greece

I have been to Greece couple of times and I'm in love with the landscape, food, aura etc. I have already visited the Cyclades islands of Santorini and Mykonos after I knew that they are most visited islands by tourists. 
The third or fourth most visited Greek island would make into my bucket list.

Comment: If you love Greece, you may get on a less touristic island (you already have some understanding of Greece, and you may have less problem on finding good things). In any case I think Crete is one of the most visited island.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Any suggestions for less touristic island ?

Comment: Get some examples from: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tourism_in_Greece (to answer the main question, so Rhodes, Corfu, Crete). Maybe some smaller island in Cyclades (check when there are ferries, you may need to land in one of the most touristic islands). Friendlier and more relaxed people.

Comment: There are no official statistics as it is very difficult to distinguish tourists from locals travelling - the airport's traffic may be an indication that Crete must be in the top 3 of islands following Mykonos and Santorini. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_the_busiest_airports_in_Greece

Comment: So you're asking for "five-star" islands? Personally, I'd like to revisit Rhodos and Delos (and add Crete, Corfu as well.)

Comment: If you need less touristic islands there are islands like Milos or Folegandros or Amorgos. Ikaria is also very nice (they all have lots of tourists but not the pandemonium that exists in Mykonos for example). Generally every island has something special so it is very unlikely for you to be disappointed no matter which one you chose.

Comment: @papakias Can you please provide your views on Antiparos and Anafi?

Comment: @Bennie I haven't been there but the locals like them a lot. They are very small islands but the Greeks consider them very good destinations (especially if you like camping).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find any official statistics but from my experience the most visited islands after Santorini and Mykonos are:

- Paros
- Naxos
- Crete
- Rhodes
- Corfu

All the islands (even the ones that are not 'most visited') are great and all are worth visiting though.

Comment: euxaristw, Paros & Naxos, so Kikhlades win. Is Rhodes from Ionian islands ?

Comment: @Bennie Rhodes is in south-eastern Aegean sea while Corfu is in the Ionian. There are 7 big islands in the Ionian and all worth visiting. But Corfu is the one that receives the most tourists. Crete on the other hand is in the very south of Greece and is the biggest island of all the Greek islands. It has many towns worth visiting and amazingly great beaches. Pick any of these islands and you will have a great time.